# Render different resolutions in AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition, catextlayer

When using `AVMutableComposition` to add a `CATextLayer` on top of a video, is there a way to render the text layer in a higher resolution than that of the video? The video is currently 1024x576, and I cannot afford to increase the bitrate or file size more than that, but adding a text layer in this render size does not look as good. Therefore, can I increase the render size and scale up the video or are there other ways to make a `CATextLayer` render smoother?

Any effect that this would have on the output bitrate or file size is acceptable.

Comment: You could choose a font that looked better at lower resolutions? QuickTime used to support text and sprites, but `AVFoundation` doesn't make these things available to you. So unless subtitles are good enough for you, I think you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

For **AVPlayer Preview** set **contentsScale**

```
layerPrimaryTextTitle.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
layerSecondaryTextTitle.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
layerPlaceHolder.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

While Export

```
layerPrimaryTextTitle.shouldRasterize = true
layerPrimaryTextTitle.contentsScale = 2.0
layerPrimaryTextTitle.rasterizationScale = 2.0
```

**shouldRasterize**

> - When true, the layer is rendered as a bitmap in its local
>   coordinate space ("rasterized"), then the bitmap is composited into
>   the destination (with the minificationFilter and
>   magnificationFilter  properties of the layer applied if the bitmap
>   needs scaling). Rasterization occurs after the layer's filters and
>   shadow effects are applied, but before the opacity modulation. As
>   an implementation detail the rendering engine may attempt to cache
>   and reuse the bitmap from one frame to the next. (Whether it does
>   or not will have no affect on the rendered output.)
> - When false the layer is composited directly into the destination
>   whenever possible (however, certain features of the compositing
>   model may force rasterization, e.g. adding filters). Defaults to
>   NO. Animatable.

**rasterizationScale**

> The scale at which the layer will be rasterized (when the
> shouldRasterize property has been set to YES) relative to the
> coordinate space of the layer. Defaults to one. Animatable.

Comment: this is not even about AVMutableComposition